# How do I add an individual testers on TestFlight for one build only?

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I've been uploading builds of my app to TestFlight, and I have a group of testers called `App Store Connect Users` that automatically gets invites every time I upload a new build. I have one new tester that I want to add to our most recent build only, and not have them included on future builds. How do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

so firstly you need to share the joining link to make sure that he has setup of test flight aswell as apple account then you go to your setup on macbook or any device from where you push the updates
There will be an option on the development of your app to add a user you add the user into it and the user will input a reedem code and will enter your environment of testing

Comment: This answer is pretty nonspecific about where to find these options, but more importantly doesn't appear to answer the question. OP is trying to add a tester to an individual build of the app, not the app in general.